# Solving an ODE with scipy.integrate.solve_bvp, the return of my function is not able to be broadcast into the appropriate array shape for solve_bvp

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, ode

I am trying to solve a second order ODE with solve_bvp. I have split the second order ODE into a system of tow first oder ODEs.  I have a changing set of constants depending on the x (mesh) value. So I am passing these as an array of shape (N,) into my function numdens. While trying to run solve_bvp I get the error that the returns have different shapes namely (N,) and (N-1,) and thus cannot be broadcast into one array. But when I check each return back manually outside of the function it has the shape (N,).
If I run the solver without my changing constants I get a solution akin to the right one.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp,odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

E_0 = 1 * 0.0000016021773 #erg: gcm^2/s^2
m_H = 1.6*10**(-24) #g
c = 3e11 #cm
sigma_c = 2*10**(-23)
n_0 = 1*10**(20)   #1/cm^3
v_0 = (2*E_0/m_H)**(0.5)  #cm/s
T = 10**7
b = 20.3
n_eq = b*T**3
n_s = 2.03*10**(19)
Q = 1 

def velocity(v,x):
    dvdx = -sigma_c*n_0*v_0*((8*v_0*v-7*v**2-v_0**2)/(2*v*c))
    return dvdx


n_num = 100
x_num = np.linspace(-1*10**(6),3*10**(6), n_num)

sol_velo = odeint(velocity,0.999999999999*v_0,x_num)

sol_new = np.reshape(sol_velo,n_num)

def constants(v):
    D1 = (c*v/(3*n_0*v_0*sigma_c))
    D2 = ((v**2-8*v_0*v+v_0**2)/(6*v))
    D3 = sigma_c*n_0*v_0*((8*v_0*v-7*v**2-v_0**2)/(2*v*c))
    return D1,D2,D3

def numdens(x,y):
    v = sol_new
    D1,D2,D3 = constants(v)
    return np.vstack((y[1],(-D2*y[1]-D3*y[0]+Q*((1-y[0])/n_eq))/(D1)))

def bc_num(ya, yb):
    return np.array([ya[0]-n_s,yb[0]-n_eq])


y_num = np.array([np.linspace(n_s, n_eq, n_num),np.linspace(n_s, n_eq, n_num)])


sol_num = solve_bvp(numdens, bc_num, x_num, y_num)




plt.plot(sol_num.x, sol_num.y[0], label='$n(x)$')
plt.plot(x_num, sol_velo-v_0/7, label='$v(x)$')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.grid(alpha=0.5)
plt.legend(framealpha=1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account that the BVP solver uses an adaptive mesh. That is, after refining the initial guess on the initial grid the solver identifies regions with overly large errors and creates new mesh nodes there. As far as I have seen, the opposite is not implemented, even if it may be in some applications sensible to reduce the number of mesh nodes on especially "nice" segments.

Thus what you are doing the the `numdens` function is incomprehensible, it has to function exactly like any other function that you would pass to an ODE solver. If I had to propose some fast fix, and without knowing what the underlying problem is that you want to solve, I would change the assignment of `v` to

```
v = np.interp(x,x_num,sol_velo)
```

as that should at least produce an array of the correct format.